# Publicar web en .Net 5.0 sobre IIS desde Visual Studio 2019 no arranca

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, visual-studio-2019, .net-5

Estoy intentando publicar una web de prueba en .Net 5.0 sobre un IIS en Windows 10.

- Tengo instalado .Net 5.0
- Tengo activado el IIS en Windows
- Tengo instalado el ASP.NET Core 5.0 Runtime (v5.0.1)
- He instalado el dotnet-hosting-5.0.1-win
- He creado la aplicación web en el IIS y le he asignado un Pool específico con la versión .Net CLR "Sin código administrado" y modo de canalización administrada "Integrada". Le he asignado el puerto 8090.
- Desde Visual Studio doy a Publish y selecciono:

  - File Sistem
  - Configuration: Release
  - Target Framework: 5.0
  - Deployment Mode: Self-Contained
  - Target Runtime: win-x86 (con win-x64 tampoco funciona)

Mi versión de Windows es 1909 (compilación de SO 18363.1256)

Si navego a la ruta http://localhost:8090/ obtengo este error "HTTP Error 500.32 - Failed to load .NET Core host"

He hecho iisreset, he borrado y he vuelto a crear la aplicación, he reiniciado Windows, pero me sigue sin cargar la web de ejemplo.

No sé qué más mirar. ¿Alguna idea o sugerencia?

[image: Configuración de publicación en Visual Studio 2019]

[image: Error que me aparece]

Comment: El log de errores sería de mucha utilidad para ver qué está pasando realmente. Te recomiendo que loggees todo lo que sucede en la aplicación en formato txt para poder debuggarla cuando no la tienes en el IDE

Comment: El visor de eventos me devuelve estos errores:

Unable to load 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\PruebaNetCore\.\hostfxr.dll'. This might be caused by a bitness mismatch between IIS application pool and published application.

Could not find 'aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll'. Exception message:

Failed to start application '/LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT', ErrorCode '0x800700c1'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He conseguido ver por qué era:

Cuando me daba el error 500.32 es porque tenía que poner a True en el Pool la opción "Enable 32-bit applications" [Enable 32-bit applications en .Net Core (Fix .NET Core HTTP Error 500.32)](https://codingschnauzer.azurewebsites.net/2019/10/27/net-core-unable-to-load-hostfxr-dll-this-might-be-caused-by-a-bitness-mismatch-between-iis-application-pool-and-published-application/)

Para solucionar el error 500.30 hay que forzarle a que borre los archivos antes de pubicar tal y como sugiere este artículo [Fix .NET Core HTTP Error 500.30 After Publish to App Service from Visual Studio](https://build5nines.com/fix-net-core-http-error-500-30-after-publish-to-app-service-from-visual-studio/)

Nota muy importante que también me estaba volviendo loco y me daba error "denied": Dar permisos de modificación a la carpeta donde irá publicada la aplicación web.

Con eso debería publicarse sin problemas.

Aunque he leído en algún artículo que .Net Core bloquea algunas librerías, con lo que recomiendan parar la aplicación en el IIS (e incluso el Pool) para asegurarnos. Después de publicar.